# What should I use to be sure that a block of code is executed together in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, atomic

I have a 3 layer web app in C#.

I have a simple method in the business layer that calls another one in the database layer to insert info in the database.

When the control return to the business layer, I checked the result variable, and if it's positive it means that the info was inserted in the database. Then, if positive, I called another method to send an email.

I was wondering, that would happen if the server goes offline just in the middle of this? For example just after the info was inserted but before the mail was dispatched.

How can I solve this situation and make this block of code run in an atomic way? Using a transaction? (not sure how to use one through different methods in different class libraries).

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are really serious search term is [two-phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). Otherwise there is nothing really small and concrete to be answerable in SO post...

Comment: If you are using SQL Server for data and Exchange for email, you could look at MSDTC but its an answer, rather than the answer. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd337629(v=ws.10).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145032(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate these issues. Have your business layer write the values, with a new field "MailSent" or something set to False. Have another service poll the results table for unsent mails, and work through those.

Comment: Of course, you need to be careful here to not send duplicate mails in which you successfully send an email but fail to update the DB to indicate that you did so.

Comment: @Servy: There will always be a chance for it to go wrong, but the odd duplicate email is better than not sending one at all (+1, A good solution)

Comment: @musefan That depends on the context.

Comment: @Servy: True, but if you are going to go through this effort to ensure an email is sent then it is likely 2 is better than 0. Otherwise OP could stick with current approach and just ignore the odd failures

Comment: @musefan That's my point though; neither technically solve the problem being asked of doing the operations atomically.  It's changing one problem for another, not solving it.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, but I am not sure there is a way to get 100% reliability. It might not solve the problem, but it does improve the reliability

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes. The email technology might ensure us that a mail has been SENT, but we NEVER know if it arrived. Or was received. Or read. Or marked as spam... Meaning if you USE e-mail, you will have to calculate in some loss...

Answer (score 1):

You can run all of your database operations within a transaction, but you truly can't ensure that the mail is being sent out in the middle of the transaction.  Even thought you can dispatch an email to a smtp server for delivery, the mail DELIVERY IS NOT GUARANTEED ANYHOW!!!

1. The mail server may be unable to connect outward toward the internet or wherever it has to relay mail to.
2. It may be able to connect out, but weird stuff happens and the message may be delayed (as in the case where it connects right away, but connection is dropped)

Don't drive yourself crazy.  It's a short drive.

Answer (score 1):

Sending an email via relay sometimes takes time, so you do not want to wait whether email is fail or successful.

However, there is not right or wrong answer. Here is my two cents.

As you said, **second code of block is sending email**. In our sites, **we use separate process to send out emails**. Here is how it works –

1. Use transaction to enter information to **Info table** and **EmailQueue** table in database
2. Background process picks up emails from **EmailQueue** (let say every 5 minutes) and send out email
3. If email is successful, mark the email as sent
4. If email is fail, increase the attempt counter until it reach some limits (let say 3 times)
5. **If server goes offline like you said** and come backup again, the background process will pick up emails from EmailQueue *(which haven't been send and less than attempt limits)*.

Answer (score 0):

Inspite of returning a boolean result. Maintain a table called Outbox and insert a row in it if condition satisfies.

And when control comes back to your business layer as mentioned in your question. Process all the outbox mails i.e., sent all the mails present in outbox and delete the entry from outbox or update a column in Outbox table which will represent email status.